# Fallo en el Intent

Tags: java, android

Saludo a todos, soy un desarrollador aficionado de Android y quiero abrir un archivo de Excel con un botón en mi aplicación, pero no funciona, lo he intentado todo pero hay algo mal que no noté, tal vez en el manifiesto o en algún lugar más.

Aquí está mi código de mainActivity, por favor ayúdame a encontrar el error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button intentButton;
        private TextView tvContainer;
        private TextView linked;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            intentButton = findViewById(R.id.intentButton);
            tvContainer = findViewById(R.id.tvContainer);
            linked = findViewById(R.id.linked);

            intentButton.setOnClickListener(openFile);

        }


        private View.OnClickListener openFile = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                String directorioRaiz = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Excels/2-6.xlsx";
                System.out.println(directorioRaiz);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(directorioRaiz);
                System.out.println(uri.getPath());
                sendIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.ms-excel");
                String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);

                if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(chooser);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Porfa una ayudita

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor especifica el error que te da...

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración ya puse lo que pasa, es que mi botón solo abre la aplicación excel pero sale un mensaje de que no se puede abrir el documento que quiero

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes reemplazar tu llamada por lo siguiente:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                 "RUTA_DE_TU_ARCHIVO");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); // Intenta con URI from FILE dado que estas partiendo desde un archivo desde tu storage
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Espero te ayude :)